# 4CT for infinite aperiodic planar graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colorings

Inspired by the recent Einstein 'Hat' tiling.
Is Appel & Haken's proof still applicable to an *infinite aperiodic* graph ? Such a graph with 1 region less still remains an infinite graph, right? How to apply the reduction principle then?

A link: [Greedy coloring for infinite graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263420/greedy-coloring-for-infinite-graphs)

Comment: This follows from the [De_Bruijn-Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)), so infinite planar graphs are 4-colorable.